# C++ CPP Calling a DLL dynamically with parameters

Tags: c++, dll

I am not C++-professional yet. I am doing my master thesis and mainly programming. There will be 4 DLLs and one exe in the end.
I googled some stuff, how to compile dlls and stuff and already made a dll from a "template". Now, the question is: How do I call a dll dynamically from cpp with parameters?

This is my code (mainly from [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/dll/dll_writing.htm)):

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdexcept>

typedef VOID (*DLLPROC) (LPTSTR);

HINSTANCE hinstDLL;
DLLPROC HelloWorld;
BOOL fFreeDLL;

hinstDLL = LoadLibrary("Test-DLL.dll");

if (hinstDLL != NULL)
{
   HelloWorld = (DLLPROC) GetProcAddress(hinstDLL, "hello");

   if (HelloWorld != NULL)
      (HelloWorld);

   fFreeDLL = FreeLibrary(hinstDLL);
}
```

The function to be called is `hello(const char *s)`. How do I pass the `*s` to the dll?

Comment: `const char* msg = "my message"; HelloWorld(msg);`

Answer (score 0):

typedef VOID (*DLLPROC) (LPTSTR);   is the signature of the function you're expecting - which should probably be in your case

typedef VOID (*DLLPROC) (const char *);

The first item is the return type of the function - the contents of the first brackets is what you wish to call it; and the contents of the second brackets are the arguments.

HelloWorld is your function pointer into the dll - syntactically, calling the function is the same as calling a staticly compiled library function; thus you just need to do

HelloWorld("dave")
to call your function with the argument "dave".

You may wish to have a quick look at 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/64tkc9y5.aspx

for an example.

Comment: Thank you - got caught by char* being formatted for me!